# Outputting an AWK variable for database INSERT, escaping single quote and backslash

Tags: mysql, awk, quotes

So I am running through a directory deriving names to insert into a MySQL database.
Some of the names have a single quote ('). I'm using awk

```
ls *| awk -F=: '{print "INSERT into citation_sources (source_name) VALUES (" "'\''" $1 "'\''" ");"}'
```

While I can get the output to appear properly from awk. 
E.G.:

```
INSERT into citation_sources (source_name) VALUES ('Black's Law Dictionary, 2nd Edition (Black 1891));
```

When it's time to insert the data into MySQL I'd like to avoid having to do a second data edit to properly escape the single quote with `\'`.

What am I missing in my awk to do this for me?

Comment: add more '\' chars? i.e. `... VALUES (" "'\\\''" $1 ";\\\''" ")` . Don't have time to test. I've seen cases where 5 or more are required. Good luck.

Comment: also, don't you want the VALUES in your final INSERT statement to be surrounded by dbl-quotes, i.e. `VALUES("'Black's...)");`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It is simplest to solve this before it gets to awk. If you don't have an ancient `ls`, just add -Q (quote) to the parameter list:

```
$ ls -Q * | awk -F=: '{print "INSERT into citation_sources (source_name) VALUES (" "'\''" $1 "'\''" ");"}'
INSERT into citation_sources (source_name) VALUES ('"Black's Law Dictionary, 2nd Edition (Black 1891)"');
```

This is when you should consider how you really want the values to be quoted, as @shellter said.

Alternatively pipe it through sed or similar first, to get the backslashes in (eg `sed "s,',\\\\',g"`).

To solve it by escaping just with awk is tricker than one may think, since bash eats up the quotes and escapes. Producing the '\' is thus the most challenging bit and I ended up with out-of-awk shell generation for it to survive:

```
$ ls * | awk -F=: "{print \"INSERT into citation_sources (source_name) VALUES ('\" gensub(\"'\",\""$'\\\\'"\\\'\",\"global\",\$1) \"');\"}"
INSERT into citation_sources (source_name) VALUES ('Black\'s Law Dictionary, 2nd Edition (Black 1891)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have this in your BEGIN{} section of your awk script.

```
echo "Black's Law D'icti'onary"|awk '{
ESC=sprintf("%c",0x5c);
SQ=sprintf("%c",0x27);
DQ=sprintf("%c",0x22);
# then perfrom a 
gsub(SQ,ESC""SQ);
# and such. same goes for other stuff.
}'
```

Handy to have :-)